# Warum »Alice, fing an sich zu langweilen« und nicht »Alice, fing sich zu langweilen an«?

Tags: grammar, word-order, separable-verb

Ich habe eine Frage. Ich habe angefangen, das Buch *Alice im Wunderland* zu lesen. Auf der ersten Seite steht folgender Satz:

> Alice, fing an sich zu langweilen; […]

Meine Frage ist: Warum nicht Folgendes?

> Alice, fing sich zu langweilen an; […]

Ich habe gelernt, dass das Präfix ans Ende des Satzes geht.

[image]

PS: I'm a begginer in German (started 1 month ago) so feel free to let me know if I have a mistake about what I wrote, or if you haven't understood at all.

Comment: Das ist aber ein alter Schinken, wenn da noch "thun" geschrieben wird!

Comment: @userunknown So basically that's old German?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: Ja; *thun* wurde mit der Rechtschreibreform von 1901 abgeschafft. Interessanterweise scheint jemand diese Fassung digitalisiert zu haben (nach Deinem Bild zu urteilen). Außerdem ist die Übersetzung sehr frei und unterschlägt einige Details und erfindet neue hinzu ([zum Vergleich](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-h/11-h.htm#link2HCH0001)).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for the comment, I bought the book on Amazon :D, I thought it would be a good book to start with German.

Comment: Mich irritiert hier eher das Komma nach "Alice"...

Comment: @Gerhard: Mich irritiert, dass mein Kommentar in der gleichen Sache gelöscht wurde. Zwar hat Victor daraufhin den Screenshot/Scan eingebaut, aber wie Dein Kommentar zeigt ist meine Frage dadurch ja nicht obsolet geworden.

Comment: Das scheint die erste Übersetzung aus dem Jahr 1869 zu sein. http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19778 s. a. http://www.sochorek.cz/de/pr/blog/1249080665-alice-im-wunderland-autor-lobt-seine-ubersetzerin.htm

Comment: Note that this picture (and thus, likely the book) has some punctuations that are considered wrong in today’s German: The comma following the first *Alice* is wrong as is placing the comma after *Bücher* inside the quotation marks (should be outside). Furthermore, I would place a comma between *an* and *sich* in the first sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In einigen Fällen kann ein Teil des Satzes (hier: „sich zu langweilen“) sowohl vor dem schließenden Teil der Verbalklammer (im Mittelfeld des Satzes) als auch danach (im Nachfeld des Satzes) stehen. Meistens gilt die Stellung im Mittelfeld als die normale Wortstellung. Wenn dagegen ein Satzglied in das Nachfeld nach dem schließenden Teil der Verbalklammer gestellt wird, spricht man von *Ausklammerung.*

Laut Duden – *Die Grammatik* können verschiedene stilistische Gründe eine Ausklammerung nahelegen; grammatisch notwendig ist sie jedoch nie.

Speziell zu *anfangen* wird in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erklärt, dass der abhängige Infinitiv ausgeklammert werden kann, wenn der Verbzusatz *an-* in den finiten Formen vom Verb getrennt und als zweiter Bestandteil der Verbalklammer nachgestellt wird:

> Danach fing sie an bitterlich zu weinen.
> (*Neben:* Danach fing sie bitterlich zu weinen an.)
>
> Wir fingen an ein Haus zu bauen.
> (*Neben:* Wir fingen ein Haus zu bauen an.)

Bei der Ausklammerung werden die zugehörigen Glieder zusammen mit dem abhängigen Infinitiv aus der Klammer herausgestellt. Das folgende Beispiel ist daher nicht korrekt, kommt allerdings umgangssprachlich vor:

> Danach fing sie bitterlich an zu weinen.

Answer (score 5):

Der Satz besteht aus dem Hauptsatz: ***Was macht Alice?*** - **Alice fängt an**. und dem Nebensatz: ***Was fängt sie an?*** - **Sich zu langweilen**. Deswegen ist es völlig legitim und natürlich, zu sagen:

> Alice fängt an, sich zu langweilen.

und ebenso

> Hör auf, rumzunörgeln!

Allerdings, per Analogie zu Sätzen wie:

> Ich fange die Arbeit jetzt an.

tendieren manche Menschen dazu, in Sätzen mit einem Nebensatz das Objekt (*die Arbeit*) durch den Nebensatz zu ersetzen:

> Ich fange zu arbeiten an.

was nach meinem Sprachgefühl weniger schön klingt.

Beispielsweise, **gefühlt** habe ich folgende Sätze:

> - Es fängt an, zu regnen.
> - Es fängt zu regnen an.

ungefähr gleich oft gehört.

Comment: Du schreibst auch kein Komma hinter "Alice"?

Comment: Nein, da gehört normalerweise kein Komma hin.

Comment: Allerdings +1 für das Komma zwischen fing an und sich zu langweilen ;)